# Сильно ли ресурсоёмко переименование файла в PHP?

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.

Пишу проект, так уж получилось, что часто нужно переименовывать названия файлов. Замечу: переименовывать без перемещения. И стало вдруг интересно, а сильно ли это трудоёмко? Ведь если да... придется переделать логику проекта совсем по другому.

Comment: Смотря что вы подразумеваете под "трудоемко". Если работа с файлами очень массивна - на жестком их лучше хранить в виде id.ext, в бд держать поля id, ext, title и менять непосредственно title (опять таки, это исключительно в том случае, если работа с файлами массивная)

Comment: так и делаю )  
спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любая работа с файловой системой ресурсоемкая, поэтому ее лучше избегать, рекомендую последовать совету [[@Intuo](/users/6962/intuo)](/users/6962/intuo)

P.S. это не зависит от языка программирования.

Comment: Дисковая подсистема имеет сравнительно малую пропускную способность, а ее увеличение очень дорогое удовольствие.

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняй в БД новые имена и указатели на переименовываемые файлы, причем хранить файлы лучше на другом сервере или жестком диске, потом давай доступ пользователям к ним через эти сохраненные в БД имена(что-то вроде псевдонимов).

Answer (score -4):

Ну если переименовать файл это часть алгоритма, то почему бы и нет. Нет, это не трудоёмко.

Comment: понял, спасибо